# How does a nozzle behave differently at different velocities of flow?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, energy, aerodynamics

A converging duct acts as a nozzle for subsonic flows while the same nozzle acts as a diffuser (decelerator) for supersonic flows?
How does this actually work?

Answer (score 1):

actually the reduction in density is more at supersonic flow compared to the increase in velocity hence area has to be increased for nozzle (i.e. it mreduced in that condition it will act as a diffuser rather than a nozzle(use conservation of mass)

Comment: I think that very clearly brings out the science behind it. You mentioned the conservation of mass...can you please elaborate further on how we work it out in this situation?